# Form.Field error and Input error properties, problem with property type

Tags: semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I noticed a problem today with Semantic UI React and using an `Input` component inside a `Form.Field` component and the usage of the `error` property:

```
const ScheduleTypeFields = ({ form }: FieldProps<JobEntryType>) => (
    <Form.Field>
        <Form.Input label='Schedule' required error={form.touched.schedule && form.errors.schedule}>
            <Input label={<Dropdown basic options={ScheduleTypes} name='cronType' id='cronType' onChange={(_, opts) => form.setFieldValue('cronType', opts.value)} onBlur={form.handleBlur} value={form.values.cronType} />}
                placeholder='Specify in CRON format, i.e. * * * * *'
                labelPosition='left' name='schedule' id='schedule' onChange={form.handleChange} onBlur={form.handleBlur} value={form.values.schedule} />
        </Form.Input>
    </Form.Field>
)
```

The problem I am facing is simple:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `error` supplied to `FormField`.
    in FormField (created by FormInput)
    in FormInput (created by ScheduleTypeFields)
    in div (created by FormField)
    in FormField (created by ScheduleTypeFields)
    in div (created by FormGroup)
    in FormGroup (created by ScheduleTypeFields)
    in ScheduleTypeFields (created by FieldInner)
    in FieldInner (created by Context.Consumer)
    in FormikConnect(FieldInner) (created by InnerJobForm)
    in form (created by Form)
    in Form (created by InnerJobForm)
    in InnerJobForm (created by Formik)
    in Formik (created by JobForm)
    in JobForm (created by CreateJob)
    in CreateJob (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (created by App)
    in Switch (created by App)
    in div (created by Container)
    in Container (created by App)
    in Router (created by App)
    in App
```

I assume the problem is with the signature for `error` in `Input` vs the signature of `error` in `Form.Field`, in the former is `boolean` while `any?` in the later and `Form.Field` is passing `error` to `Input`, hence the error.

I have to do it in this way because I have a custom label with a control in my input control, I tried using nested `component` but I couldn't, maybe I am doing something wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use Input component inside Form.Input since Form.Input renders as input in html. So, this means that you have at the end rendered something like this:

```
<input>
  <input></input>
</input>
```

which is semantically wrong and is reporting error in pure HTML as well. 
You should restructure your code a bit differently. I suggest putting Input component on the same level as Form.Input